# Portable locale codes

Tags: python, windows, locale

When I locale set "hr_HR.UTF-8" in python 3 on linux, everything goes fine. When I do it in Windows, it fails:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\nskoric>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "hr_HR.UTF-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\locale.py", line 592, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I did some googling and it turns out Windows uses it's own standard for locale codes. So, I have two questions:

1. what is Windows locale code for Croatian? (not mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf(v=vs.140).aspx), most obvious "hr-HR" does not work)
2. what is the portable way to set locale codes? (is there? or should I check which system is in use?)

Thanks!

**edit:**

Upon more googling I found locale.locale_alias and on Windows it contains:

```
'hr': 'hr_HR.ISO8859-2',
'hr_hr': 'hr_HR.ISO8859-2',
'croatian': 'hr_HR.ISO8859-2',
```

I tried hr_HR.ISO8859-2, hr and hr_hr, all failed. The only one that suceeded was croatian. So, that partialy answers my 1st question, but I still do not understand - why those 3 failed and the last one suceeded :-(

**edit2:**

This is my final solution. If somebody knows a more elegant one - please share :-)

```
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "hr_HR.UTF-8")
    except locale.Error:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "croatian")
```

Comment: Python 3.4 is built with Visual Studio 2010; see [Language and Country/Region Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3tw78%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for VS2010. This version of the Windows CRT doesn't support alpha-2 locale names that use a hyphen (e.g. "hr-HR"). It supports the full name (e.g. "Croatian_Croatia") or alpha-3 names (e.g. "hrv_hrv") using an underscore. Optionally you can set a specific codepage (e.g. "hrv_hrv.1250"), but UTF-8 (codepage 65001) isn't allowed.

Comment: @eryksun: You should make this into an answer.

Comment: If you're targeting Windows Vista or later then you can easily look up the old-style locale abbreviations by using ctypes to call [`GetLocaleInfoEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103). Call it once for  `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME` and again for `LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME`.

Comment: For example (needs error checking): `from ctypes import *;` `kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32');` `locname = u'hr_HR.utf-8';` `winloc = locname[:5].replace('_', '-');` `buf = (c_wchar * 10)();` `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME = 3;` `kernel32.GetLocaleInfoEx(winloc, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, buf, len(buf));` `lang = buf.value;` `LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME = 7;` `kernel32.GetLocaleInfoEx(winloc, LOCALE_SABBREVCTRYNAME, buf, len(buf));` `ctry = buf.value;` `locname = '_'.join([lang, ctry])`.